# D3Js Bar Chart Bars Starting Way After beginning of X-Axis

Tags: d3.js, charts, bar-chart

As the title say, I am creating a bar chart using D3Js. What do I have to change in the following snippet for the bars to start at the beginning of the X-Axis?

```js
var allBarsDatasets = [
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "10-1",
        "barValue": 18
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "10-2",
        "barValue": 17
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "10-3",
        "barValue": 17
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "10-4",
        "barValue": 19
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "11-1",
        "barValue": 19
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "11-2",
        "barValue": 14
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "11-3",
        "barValue": 18
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "11-4",
        "barValue": 12
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "12-1",
        "barValue": 16
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "12-2",
        "barValue": 15
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "12-3",
        "barValue": 14
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "12-4",
        "barValue": 15
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "13-1",
        "barValue": 16
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "13-2",
        "barValue": 17
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "13-3",
        "barValue": 12
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "13-4",
        "barValue": 17
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "14-1",
        "barValue": 17
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "14-2",
        "barValue": 16
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "14-3",
        "barValue": 14
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "14-4",
        "barValue": 15
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "15-1",
        "barValue": 15
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "15-2",
        "barValue": 19
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "15-3",
        "barValue": 17
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "15-4",
        "barValue": 12
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "16-1",
        "barValue": 13
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "16-2",
        "barValue": 17
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "16-3",
        "barValue": 17
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "16-4",
        "barValue": 19
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "17-1",
        "barValue": 18
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "17-2",
        "barValue": 13
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "17-3",
        "barValue": 17
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "17-4",
        "barValue": 16
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "18-1",
        "barValue": 10
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "18-2",
        "barValue": 15
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "18-3",
        "barValue": 17
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "18-4",
        "barValue": 17
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "19-1",
        "barValue": 18
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "19-2",
        "barValue": 14
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "19-3",
        "barValue": 16
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "19-4",
        "barValue": 13
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "20-1",
        "barValue": 15
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "20-2",
        "barValue": 17
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "20-3",
        "barValue": 14
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "20-4",
        "barValue": 16
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "21-1",
        "barValue": 18
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "21-2",
        "barValue": 14
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "21-3",
        "barValue": 17
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "21-4",
        "barValue": 15
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "22-1",
        "barValue": 16
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "22-2",
        "barValue": 17
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "22-3",
        "barValue": 16
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "22-4",
        "barValue": 16
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "23-1",
        "barValue": 16
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "23-2",
        "barValue": 16
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "23-3",
        "barValue": 15
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "23-4",
        "barValue": 16
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "24-1",
        "barValue": 15
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "24-2",
        "barValue": 15
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "24-3",
        "barValue": 17
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "24-4",
        "barValue": 13
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "6-1",
        "barValue": 16
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "6-2",
        "barValue": 16
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "6-3",
        "barValue": 16
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "6-4",
        "barValue": 15
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "7-1",
        "barValue": 12
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "7-2",
        "barValue": 18
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "7-3",
        "barValue": 15
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "7-4",
        "barValue": 18
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "8-1",
        "barValue": 16
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "8-2",
        "barValue": 15
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "8-3",
        "barValue": 17
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "8-4",
        "barValue": 16
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "9-1",
        "barValue": 17
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "9-2",
        "barValue": 14
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "9-3",
        "barValue": 18
    },
    {
        "xAxisTickValue": "9-4",
        "barValue": 18
    }
];
    // TODO: format labels and values
    // rotate x-axis ticks; if number user shorter format
    // use shorter format for y-axis values
    // correctly position x-axis and y-axis labels
    
    $("#chartDiv").html("");
    var barColor = '#384a60';
    
    // calculate total frequency by state for all segment.
    var fD = allBarsDatasets.map(function(d){return [d.xAxisTickValue,d.barValue];});
    
/*     var margin = {top: 20, right: 100, bottom: 30, left: 100},
        width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 310 - margin.top - margin.bottom;  */

    var margin = {top: 20, right: 100, bottom: 30, left: 100},
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;    
    

        var padding = 100;
            
        //create svg for histogram.
        var svg = d3.select("#chartDiv").append("svg")            
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom).append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        // create function for x-axis mapping.
        var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.1)
                .domain(fD.map(function(d) { return d[0]; }));

        // Add x-axis to the histogram svg.
        svg.append("g").attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(x)
                .orient("bottom")
                .innerTickSize(-height)
                .outerTickSize(0)
                .tickPadding(10));
        
        // create function for y-axis mapping.
        var yMin = d3.min(fD.map(function(d) { return d[1]; }));
        
        var yMax = d3.max(fD.map(function(d) { return d[1]; }));
        
        var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0])
            .domain([0, d3.max(fD, function(d) { return d[1]; })]);
        
        var yScaleGridLines = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([yMin, yMax])
            .range([height, 0]);
            
        var yAxisGridLines = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(yScaleGridLines)
            .orient("left")
            .innerTickSize(-width)
            .outerTickSize(0)
            .tickPadding(10);

        svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .call(yAxisGridLines);
        
        // Create bars for histogram to contain rectangles and freq labels.
        var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar").data(fD).enter()
                .append("g").attr("class", "bar");
        
        //create the rectangles.
        bars.append("rect")
            .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d[0]); })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
            .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
            .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d[1]); })
            .attr('fill',barColor);
```

```css
#chartDiv .axis path,
#chartDiv .axis line{
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
}

#chartDiv .line{
    fill: none;
    stroke: blue;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}

#chartDiv .tick text{
    font-size: 12px;
}

#chartDiv .tick line{
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartDiv">
</div>
```

At first I thought it was a data issue, but I don't see anything odd in it. I also, tried removing attributes from the section where I set up the X-Axis, but it didn't work.

Comment: Try setting the outerPadding like so: `d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.5, 0)`

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks  [@AndrewReid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7106086/andrew-reid) for putting me on the right track. I figured the meaning of each arguments based on your comment to my question; the second argument is the space between bars and the third one is the padding between bars and the beginning and end of the X-Axis. The following values worked for my needs `d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.1, 0)`